# Finding prime numbers up till a number

Tags: prime-factoring

I am trying to list down all the prime numbers up till a specific number e.g. 1000. The code gets slower as the number increase. I am pretty sure it is because of the for loop where (number -1) is checked by all the prime_factors. Need some advise how I can decrease the processing time of the code for larger numbers. Thanks

```
import time

t0 = time.time()
prime_list = [2]
number = 0
is_not_prime = 0
count = 0
while number < 1000:
    print(number)
    for i in range (2,number):
        count = 0
        if (number%i) == 0:
            is_not_prime = 1
        if is_not_prime == 1:
            for j in range (0,len(prime_list)):
                if(number-1)%prime_list[j] != 0:
                    count += 1
            if count == len(prime_list):
                prime_list.append(number-1)
                is_not_prime = 0
                count = 0
                break
        
    number += 1
print(prime_list)
t1 = time.time()

total = t1-t0
print(total)
```

Comment: In mathematics, the [sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) is an ancient algorithm for finding all prime numbers up to any given limit.

Comment: does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n ?

Comment: thanks this really helped

Answer (score 0):

Your solution, on top of being confusing, is very inefficient - O(n^3). Please, use the Sieve of Eratosthenes. Also, learn how to use booleans.

Something like this (not optimal, just a mock-up). Essentially, you start with a list of all numbers, 1-1000. Then, you remove ones that are the multiple of something.

```
amount = 1000

numbers = range(1, amount)
i = 1
while i < len(numbers):
  n = i + 1
  while n < len(numbers):
    if numbers[n] % numbers[i] == 0:
      numbers.pop(n)
    else:
      n += 1
  i += 1

print(numbers)
```

Finally, I was able to answer because your question isn't language-specific, but please tag the question with the language you're using in the example.

Comment: Ya that was my first try.. third day of coding. btw its python. Anyhow, I tried to understand Sieve of Eratosthenes and wrote this code thats very similar to the logic you just explained:

`t_in = time.time()
number_list = []
number = 1

while number<100000:
 number += 1
 number_list.append(number)

i = 2

while i < number:
 for j in number_list:
  if(j%i)==0:
   if(j!=i):
    number_list.remove(j)
 i += 1
t_out = time.time()
total = t_out-t_in
print(total, number_list)`

Comment: So what do you need help with now?

Comment: nothing. Thanks :)

Comment: Ok. You can mark it as accepted if it answers the question.